# About gaining weight

Tags: weight-gain

I'm 19 years old, 5"7 tall and weight 45kg.
What should I do to gain at least 10kg within 1 month without supplements? And is my height normal?

Comment: Adding 22.5 pounds in a month... I think you'd be hospitalized

Answer (score 2):

10kg weight gain in 1 month is likely to be mostly fat, and I don't think it's a realistic goal. Why do you want to gain 10kg in one month?

If you want to gain weight really quickly, just increase your calorie intake. Eat a lot of food. Drink a lot of milk.

If you want to gain weight in a way that will be good for you, you'll need to include a well-rounded strength training program such as [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/) or Stronglifts so that you turn those extra calories into muscle, rather than fat. Even on these programs, 10kg in one month is not realistic.

Your height is normal.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to gain weight that fast, however you will be able to gain weight if you increase your calorie intake massively.

If you don't care how you look you can read up about how Matt Damon and other actors put on weight by eating junk food all day.

But hopefully you want to be healthy and be in shape, so you need to do massive compound exercises such as leg press, shoulder press and bench press with free weights.

Then you need to eat every 2 hours mostly protein and carbs.  Minimum 6 meals a day.  I am talking 3 steaks, 4 chicken breasts, fruit, wholegrain pasta, cheese, 6 glasses of milk, 6 eggs - you literally have to be constantly feeding yourself.

Then you need to organise your supplements - protein shakes 3 times a day etc.